# Azure Service Bus TimedOut exception when running within K8S instance but not in docker on node host

Tags: networking, azure, kubernetes

I'm getting a "ServiceBusCommunicationException" reason "Connection timed out ErrorCode: TimedOut" with an Inner Exception of "SocketException" reason "Connection timed out" when running a .net core 3.1 application in a docker container running in K8S.

K8S is running on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

When I run the container directly on the host of the node itself (i.e. not in K8S) the connection is fine and it processes messages ok but in K8S I get the above error. There is no firewall running on the host. The containers are based on the mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:3.1-buster-slim image. There is nothing else added to this or any other tweaks made.

This suggests a K8S issue, possibly networking, with the AQMP port itself.

K8S reports no network policies in place.

As part of the same container I have a chron job that runs that makes an http GET to the google URL. This continually reports OK (200).

Therefore (at least for HTTP) the pods are communicating with the internet fine.

If I change the authentication credentials to something "bad" I get an unauthorised error ... so it does appear to be routing ok for authorisation but not when actually connecting to do some work.

I'm not sure where to go with this. Any advice?

Comment: Are you using AKS, or running your own Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: I'm running my own K8S cluster. Installed using default scripts - nothing special as far as I know. I've checked network policies (kubectl get netpol -A) and there is nothing defined. K8S version 1.18.3

Comment: ok - so it appears that this is actually working after all. I'm just getting very regular timeout errors raised by the SDK. Intermittently, messages are processed so it appears that it is connecting when it can. What is odd is that running under docker in the host doesn't generate these TimeOut errors but running under K8S does.

Comment: Any reason  your rolling your own cluster? Using an AKS cluster will likely resolve any network issues, and won't cost you any more

Comment: One reason is to make sure I understand exactly how K8S works on bare-metal. The other is zero cost of for the hosts (we already have the hardware), the third is that we are migrating from an Azure WebApps architecture to full docker/K8S (and want to experiment freely) and the fourth is that we are likely to be prevented from using Azure/AWS cloud architectures long term (security/taxation purposes) so need to run bare-metal. Access to the service bus from on-premise is one part of our migration path.

Comment: Ah right, sorry for some reason I had assumed you were running K8s on VMs in Azure. If your getting intermittent connection my suspicion would be the connection between Kubernetes and Azure rather than networking in Kubernetes. Are there any firewalls in the way, or other things that might be slowing down traffic?